# order items of a table

Tags: list-manipulation

I am trying to change order of a table.

```
n1 := {6.`, 3.31791383741595`, 2.549684922097378`, 2.2444170593578363`,
2.109892159984955`, 2.0489264006542918`, 2.0214035890309514`, 2.009186379955868`,
2.0038735759286572`, 2.0016085340677456`, 2.0006594467480365`, 2.000267493804639`}

ListLinePlot[n1, DataRange -> {0, 11}]
```

This is for the graph with the datarange from 0 to 11. However I want to get the graph start at -11 and end at 0. (From the table, n1, 6 is at 0 and 3.3179 is at -1, 2.54 is at -2,...,2.0002674 is at -11.) Is there any good way to do this?

Comment: Does `ListLinePlot[n1 // Reverse, DataRange -> {-11, 0}]` suit your needs?

Comment: The title is very misleading, as this has nothing to do with `Table`, but with lists and plotting.

Answer (score 2):

J.M.'s suggestion (in the comments) is simple and effective.

Another way is to assign an x-axis value to each datapoint like so:

```
points1 = Transpose[{-1*(Range@Length@n1 - 1), n1}]
```

> {{0, 6.}, {-1, 3.31791}, {-2, 2.54968}, {-3, 2.24442}, 
>   {-4, 2.10989}, {-5, 2.04893}, {-6, 2.0214}, {-7, 2.00919}, 
>   {-8, 2.00387}, {-9, 2.00161}, {-10, 2.00066}, {-11, 2.00027}}

Then use `ListPlot` instead of `ListLinePlot`like:

```
ListPlot[points1,Joined->True]
```

[image]

Depending on your reasons for plotting these numbers (and what you want to do with them next) this may be a more versatile approach.

Comment: Better to use something like `Range[0, -11, -1]`, I'd think. One might also consider `MapIndexed[]` in this case.